# Can I mention multi mysql server nodes in the connection when connecting from client?

Tags: mysql, galera

i have 3 nodes. Have installed mysql on all 3. DO i need to use a load balancer mandatorily or can i mention 3 nodes separated by comma ',' in the connection when connecting from client?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this depends on the client, because it's a client's job to attempt the connection, then fallback to an alternate etc.

According to the [MySQL Connector/J](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-config-failover.html) docs for Java, you can add multiple hosts to the configuration string.

```
jdbc:mysql://[primary host][:port],[secondary host 1][:port][,[secondary host 2][:port]]...[/[database]][?propertyName1=propertyValue1[&propertyName2=propertyValue2]...]
```

This may not be true for all languages or drivers -- please let us know which language+driver you're using if you want a better answer.